# How to determine if you're on the Buddypress activity stream

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

A content filter function defined in functions.php runs well on many posts on our WordPress site, however, we do not want it to run on the BuddyPress activity stream pages. We have excluded it easily from normal WordPress pages and category listings by simply checking:

```
if ( (is_page() == false) && (is_category() == false) )
```

Which works fine. Is there a Buddypress equivalent to is_page or is_category that would identify if you're on an activity stream? Something like:

```
is_activity();
```

Or is there any other way to determine this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it with bp_is_current_component('activity')